# Can Paypal for digital goods be integrated into a Blogger blog

Tags: paypal, download, blogger, blogspot, paypal-digital-goods

I realized that Paypal for digital goods have a Javascript overlay payment method for digital goods, but after paying I'm not sure about how the downloading is been triggered. Is there a way to do it without going to the server side, as I'm running a Blogger blog?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it isn't possible.
Due to security reasons, server side processing is required with the Paypal digital goods process.  Without access to local server side, you will need to use one of the other Paypal products that manages the entire payment process on their side.

Answer (score 0):

There are two items to discuss, *payment* and *product download*.

1. Using PayPal Digital Goods, you can let the customer pay for your digital good online. Once completed, you will receive instant notification from PayPal, where you will need to....
2. Do something to present the download link to the customer.  This is not something provided by Paypal, you will need to display an Order Confirmation window with a download link to the customer, or provide some other method to deliver your product such as email.

Just make sure you secure the download link so you're not giving away free product.

Comment: This will require server side access will it not? Dnu_12 has implied that they cannot get server side access.

Comment: Since the PayPal Digital Goods process requires server-side access with PayPal, I read the question as whether it is possible to start the download from client-side.

Comment: How do you "secure the download link" without hitting the server to check that a payment has been made and deliver a "secure" link? That has to be done *after* the payment has been made, and doing that determination on the client would be, almost by definition, *insecure*.

Comment: If "going to the server side" truly isn't an option, then both PayPal DG  and secure links are out of the picture, as they both require server-side access.  Since the question was about kicking off the download after payment with PayPal DG (hence server-side), I tailored my answer to help clarify payment vs. download.

Comment: The question was, "Is there a way to do it without going to the server side,". Your associate, Jimmyb, answered correctly, in the negative.